# GDM login loops. Startx works

Tags: xorg, gnome3, login-screen, awesome-wm, gdm

I have just installed Arch Linux in my laptop.

I have awesome window manager, and I can start it from the tty with startx. When I install GDM (as I would like to have my computer start directly from GUI with a conventional login screen) and `systemctl enable gdm.service` + reboot and enter my password, the screen will turn black for some seconds and will return me to the login screen. Every time.

I have copied .Xauthority from my root folder to my user one and chowned it, created the files [as seen here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1367-running-the-awesome-window-manager-within-gnome), purged the packages and reinstalling; but nothing works.

**HOW TO REPRODUCE:**

1. Fresh Arch Linux install from LiveCD.
2. Create your user + password.
3. `pacman -S gdm gnome`
4. `systemctl enable gdm.service`
5. `pacman -S awesome`
6. Add 'exec awesome' to .xinitrc.

At this point you should be able to `startx` to get to Awesome. After a reboot, the login screen will appear and you should be facing my error.

**EXTRA INFO:**

I have tried LightDM and it works perfectly, but the GNOME issue still bugs me and I want to solve it ASAP. I am attaching my logs:

1. **JOUNALCTL -E -U GDM**

[Basically starts normally, but says my display lasted for a bit more than a second]

2. **DMESG**

`gnome-session-f[747]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f3d4eb1e5c9 sp 00007ffcdd40df00 error 4 in libgtk-3.so.0.2200.2[7f3d4e83c000+6f3000]`

Comment: use `lightdm` or post any error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fresh new install of Arch Linux following the official guide will solve the problem.